# How to re - rendering date picker

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui

How to render an existing jquery datePicker based upon new values upon ajax post? And how do I change the start date of display based upon a particular date in the ajax post

Answer (score 1):

1. Fire a function, that generates the date picker, when the ajax response is ready.
2. jQuery date picker has option defaultDate, which You can also change, when rendering new version of date picker.